# Python throws error when trying to do Py.import

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I am new to Python and I have a simple Python script with a simple method. I tried to call the method the said method in C#.  I have the codes

```
Runtime.PythonDLL = @".......\python311.dll";
PythonEngine.Initialize();
using (Py.GIL())
{
    dynamic notebook = Py.Import(@"E:/testingPython/InC/test");

    // Call the method and pass the user query
    dynamic result = notebook.consume_Testing("");

    // Use the result as needed
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

The code Py.Import(@"E:/testingPython/InC/test") is throwing an errors that says : Python.Runtime.PythonException: No module named 'E:/testingPython/InC/test'

what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is caused by how you're attempting to import the Python script/module from C#. The 'Py.Import()' method expects the module name, not the file location.

When you use a file path instead of a module name, you get the following error: "Python.Runtime.No module named 'E:/testingPython/InC/test' found."

To fix this, make sure your Python script (test.py) is in a directory that Python recognizes as a module. This can be accomplished by either adding the script's directory to the Python sys.path or transforming the script into a package by placing it in a directory with a '**init**.py' file.

Here's a step-by-step guide to resolve the issue:

1. Create a directory structure as follows:

```
E:/testingPython/InC/
   └── __init__.py
   └── test.py
```

Make sure you have an empty `__init__.py` file in the "InC" directory, which makes it a package.

2. Update your C# code to import the module correctly:

```cs
Runtime.PythonDLL = @".......\python311.dll";
PythonEngine.Initialize();

using (Py.GIL())
{
    dynamic notebook = Py.Import("InC.test"); // Updated the module name

    // Call the method and pass the user query
    dynamic result = notebook.consume_Testing("");

    // Use the result as needed
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

We removed the absolute path and replaced it with '"InC.test"'. In this scenario, this is the proper way to refer to the Python module.

Now, your C# code should be able to correctly import the 'test' module, and you may call the 'consume_Testing' method as intended.

### I wish this will help!